# PUG+Express+Jquery+bootstrap

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render PUG page in NodeJS, the problem with jQuery.

```
script(language='javascript', src='js/bootstrap.min.js')  //works fine

script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js') //**Not working**

script(src='javascripts/jquery.js')   //javascripts folder in "public"  - **not working.**
```

Same (working) logic for bootstrap:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));   
//not working for jquery:
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));
script(src='/jquery.js')                 //**Not working**
```

jquery is installed as a package with npm. 
How to include Jquery to pug?

[image: Expected result and actual result]

Comment: Is your path is right?

Comment: I've tried all the variations of paths. I guess it is not right. But i m out of ideas what to try.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: there was an error like put jQuery before bootstrap, i did. Browser error disappeared. But still looks like jQuery not loaded. I think it is because of path. I checked all tutorials possible, and it never worked.

Comment: Are you trying to load both jquery? one from `code.jquery.com` and one from local? If yes, then it might not work, use only one.

Comment: No, this are just examples of what I try. Ofc I use 1 instance of jquery (either from local server or remote server). Never works.

Comment: Spent all day trying to find a problem with jquery, and it was becase of css. I found out this after checking dev console in browser. I'm very new in front end, sorry for newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem. The Jquery was ok, the problem was with css that couldn't load and display what showed on attached image (expected result).

If you have a screen like on image, or similar. 
Please check your css file in PUG.

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/1.css')
```

This will add css to your page, if css has name "1.css" and located in folder "public". 
Also, dont forget to locate folder "public" for your app (in your server js file):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```